# Как правильно удалить обработчик событий, чтобы он мог срабатывать несколько раз без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript

Код ищет репозитории на гитхабе. Есть обработчики событий, но знаю, что хороший тон их удалять после работы. Если добавляю удаление, то событие срабатывает один раз, например один репозиторий добавляется и все.
Как удалить обработчики событий без потери функциональности?

```js
const searchForm = document.querySelector("input");
const searchFormContainer = document.querySelector(".dropdown-container");
const selectedRepository = document.querySelector(".chosens");

function a(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (!target.classList.contains("btn-close")) {

    return;
  }
  target.parentElement.remove();

};
selectedRepository.addEventListener("click", a);


function b(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (!target.classList.contains("dropdown-content")) {

    return;
  }

  addRepository(target);
  searchForm.value = "";
  removeRepository();

};
searchFormContainer.addEventListener("click", b);


function removeRepository() {
  searchFormContainer.innerHTML = "";
}

function showSelectedRepository(repositories) {
  removeRepository();

  for (let repositoryIndex = 0; repositoryIndex < 5; repositoryIndex++) {
    let name = repositories.items[repositoryIndex].name;
    let owner = repositories.items[repositoryIndex].owner.login;
    let stars = repositories.items[repositoryIndex].stargazers_count;

    let drop = `<div class="dropdown-content" data-owner="${owner}" data-stars="${stars}">${name}</div>`;
    searchFormContainer.innerHTML += drop;
  }
}

function addRepository(target) {
  let name = target.textContent;
  let owner = target.dataset.owner;
  let stars = target.dataset.stars;

  selectedRepository.innerHTML += `<div class="chosen">Name: ${name}<br>Owner: ${owner}<br>Stars: ${stars}<button class="btn-close"></button></div>`;
}

async function getSelectedRepository() {
  const urlSearchRepositories = new URL("https://api.github.com/search/repositories");
  let repositoriesPart = searchForm.value;
  if (repositoriesPart == "") {
    removePreds();
    return;
  }

  urlSearchRepositories.searchParams.append("q", repositoriesPart)
  try {
    let response = await fetch(urlSearchRepositories);
    if (response.ok) {
      let repositories = await response.json();
      showSelectedRepository(repositories);
    } else return null;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}

function cancellation(fn, timeout) {
  let timer = null;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      timer = setTimeout(
        () => resolve(fn(...args)),
        timeout,
      );
    });
  };
}

const deleteGetSelectedRepository = cancellation(getSelectedRepository, 500);
searchForm.addEventListener("input", deleteGetSelectedRepository);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 62px auto 0px auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.dropdown-container {
  min-height: 227px;
}

.dropdown input {
  border: none;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown-content {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
  background-color: #65CDF9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chosens {
  width: 503px;
}

.chosen {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #E27BEB;
}

.btn-close {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/863/842/png-clipart-iphone-x-color-pink-pastel-fashion-spotlight-miscellaneous-blue.png");
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: contain;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 42px;
  height: 38.5px;
  right: 17px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <input name="search" type="text" value="" />
    <div class="dropdown-container">
    </div>
    <div class="chosens"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `removeEventListener` - удаляет обработчик. Если ты хочешь что-то другое - стоит добавить описание.

Comment: какая последовательность действий должна быть, чтобы увидеть ошибку?

Comment: Например, добавить в функцию function a(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (!target.classList.contains("btn-close")) {

    return;
  }
  target.parentElement.remove();
selectedRepository.removeEventListener("click", a);
};
selectedRepository.addEventListener("click", a);

Comment: Отредактируй сниппет так, чтобы ошибка воспроизводилась. Конкретно сейчас выглядит что работает, как и ожидается.

Comment: _хороший тон их удалять после работы_ - удалять надо, когда они не нужны. Если они еще нужны - нет смыслы их удалять